# Custom Sort on NSFetchRequest

Tags: xcode, core-data, nssortdescriptor

When performing a `NSFetchRequest` on Core Data, I want to sort the results based off a custom selector instead of one of the entity's attributes. My best solution right now is to use a `NSSortDescriptor` on the results after the fetch has been performed. This isn't ideal for me though because I would like to use a 
`NSFetchedResultsController`, and with a `NSFetchedResultsController` I wouldn't be able to run a `NSSortDescriptor` on the results after they were fetched.

Comment: Can you add more details about the derived attribute you want to sort?

Comment: @rbrown the model is contact which has attributes like email, name, phone number. I want to sort based on a method I call summaryDescriptor which shows the name if available, if not then the phone number, if not then the email, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQLite as your store, you are limited by what you can sort with.  The limitation is what can be turned into a SQLite `order by`.

In your case you are probably better off using a NSFRC as your monitor of changes and then put a `NSArray` in front of it that is sorted the way you want.  This will require you to do some clever work whenever a change comes in to minimize your table redraws but it shouldn't be too onerous.

Answer (score 2):

Using a custom selector for your sorting means you will need to sort the items in memory. If you potentially have a large database this could mean some performance troubles for your application. Maybe try to perform the calculation of the attribute on insertion and expanding the result into a new attribute for your entity.